# Spring security OAuth 2

Tags: java, spring, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I already have an example completely working with Spring Oauth 2 (https://github.com/elohalili/OAuth) that i customized a little bit, but i really can not understand one thing:

in this example to use the resources services i should have a token from the OAuth server, so it redirects the user to that log-in page, the credentials are stored in a database but not the client id and client secret for OAuth (acme : acmesecret);
And also in the client the only client id and client secret passed are (acme : acmesecret), so all the clients that will log-in the OAuth server will be logged with the same client id and secret, that is wrong!

My question is how can i manage the client id and secret in a dynamic way so that any user that logs-in will be logged with his own credentials?
And how the client can already know the user's client id and secret to pass them to the OAuth server?

Answer (score 0):

`clientID` and `clientSecret` are credentials for application, that want to authorize token, not for user and password.
I don't know much about OAuth2 (https://oauth.net/2/) but I know in OIDC (http://openid.net/connect/) there is possibility to dynamically register new clients. Clients are applications, not users e.g.

Person (uses username:password) -> Android app/ IOS app (client clientId:clientSecret) -> resource server